# Como importar el SDK del API de PayPal para Java a mi proyecto

Tags: java, paypal

Necesito ver como importar el SDK del API de PayPal ya que descargue el SDK de GitHub pero no se cuales son los archivos que necesito agregar a mi proyecto así como su configuración.

Comment: Revisa este  [tutorial](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/integrate-paypal-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Existe en github un proyecto que te puede ayudar

Debes importar la liberia si usas maven

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
 <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
 <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

o con gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:rest-api-sdk:+'
}
```

Posteriormente debes conseguir el client ID para utilizar la Api

te dejo el [ejemplo](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK)